# TS Plot Label Size Changing

Tags: r, plot, time-series, figure

```
ts_plot(df1, 
    title = "Soil Temperature over Time",
    Xtitle = "Time",
    Ytitle = "Soil Temperature (mm)",
    dash = "dash")
```

I am trying to change the size of my text in the x and y axis, but the cex. functions are not fitting and I can't seem to plot the ts_plot function.

Please let me know if you have any helpful hints.

```
plot(ts(df1, 
         title = "Soil Temperature over Time",
         Xtitle = "Time",
         Ytitle = "Soil Temperature (mm)",
         dash = "dash"))

         axis(2, cex.axis =0.5)
         axis(1, cex.axis =1.2)
```

this does not work, nor does adding in the cex functions into the overall code.